# python search if elements in a list are a subset of another list without built in functions

Tags: python, list, search

I'm trying to search if elements in a list are a subset of another list without using built in functions like 'set' or 'if item in list'. I have the following code but I keep getting errors for 'index out of range'

```
def letterSearch(sublist,mainlist):
    x = 0
    index = 0
    while x < len(mainlist):
        if sublist[index] == mainlist[x]:
            index = index + 1
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x + 1


x = ['d','g']
y = ['d','g','a','b']

letterSearch(x,y)
print(index)
```

Comment: `len()` is a built in function

Comment: len() is okay, sorry I mean more like built in search functions

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**:

Your code increments `index` value beyond the length of `sublist`. So next time when you compare, there is no item at that index resulting in `index out of range` error.

**Solution**:

```
def letterSearch(sublist,mainlist):
    x = 0
    index = 0
    while x < len(mainlist):
        if len(sublist) != index and sublist[index] == mainlist[x]:
            index = index + 1
        x += 1 
    if len(sublist) == index:
        return index

x = ['d','g']
y = ['d','g','a','b']

index = letterSearch(x,y)
print(index)  # 2

# To display if x is a subset of y or not:
if index:
    print('{} is a subset of {}'.format(x, y))
else:
    print('Not a subset')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to find if all elemsnts of sublist are contained in mainlist.

```
def letterSearch(subList, mainList):
    for i in subList:
        found = False
        for j in mainList:
            if j == i:
                found = True
        if not found:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: thank you! I just wanted to know why is the 'return True' at the very bottom neccessary??

Comment: Its necessary because the function returns False if the elements of subList are not contained, else True. If you omit the return True statement if all the elements are contained the function returns None because no return statement will be hit. You obtain a functions that returns None or False, I think it's not a good idea, but if you know this behaviour you could use it as you like.